# How can you reuse a ServicePrincipal across Azure AD and MSol?

Tags: azure, office365, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell

I have a multitenant read only app registered in Azure AD that provides access to read Azure resources as a ServicePrincipal granted the "Reader" role and perms for "Read Directory Data". One aspect I want to grab is if MFA is enabled for an admin, which I can only get when using `Get-MsolUser`.... `GetAzureADUser` doesn't seem to hold the right information.

I need to therefore use this ServicePrincipal when calling `Connect-MsolService`... which will always fail with "Authentication Error: Bad username or password."

Now I know I could create a new ServicePrincipal specifically for Msol using `New-MsolServicePrincipal`, but I was wondering if there is some way to reuse the ServicePrincipal already registered in Azure AD for my app so I can ultimately call `Get-MsolUser` in that context? I would like to reduce the number of accounts/creds left in the customer's tenant, and if I can avoid creating multiple ServicePrincipals just to accomplish this one query, it would be better.

Comment: If you're using a same Service prinicipal, the permissions should be same. Both Msol and AADv2 powershell are based on API. Permissions are authorized with oauth. So, I suggest you check the permissions in that AAD application settings and hit the Grant permissions again.

Comment: Hey Wayne, `Connect-MsolService` doesn't seem to allow me to pass in the ServicePrincipal creds. When I try I just get bad username or password, even though the exact same `PSCredential` is used successfully to call `Login-AzureRmAccount` earlier in the script. Thoughts on how to debug the auth failure?